# How to show UITabbar with large title

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have 4 UITabbars which are showing 4 different view controllers. And those 4 UITabbars have the following name

1. ALL USER MANUES
2. ALL MANAGER Schedule
3. ALL MANAGER REPORTS
4. SYSTEM UTILITIES

NOW these titles are overlapping with each other and are really hard to see them on iPhone 6s plus. here is a picture of real device for reference. See the UI Tabbar and you will notice how bad it is looking

***PROBLEM***

> The main problem is my client is not ready to cut short these titles
>   and he want the bottom control (UITabbar)

**I set all this by Storyboard. so there is no code to share. But I am very much amazed that apple has not managed to properly align these UITabbar titles.**

If is there any way to do that please let me know. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1:**

> I wonder why isnt there any more button and any slide applied by apple
>   developers by default for the following scenario. I think this can be
>   solved if there is any more button and showing only 2 View controller
>   on UITabbar and 2 inside the more button

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> The main problem is my client is not ready to cut short these titles and he want the bottom control (UITabbar).

In my view, the main problem is your client himself because tab bar items aren't made for displaying such titles: a better design approach needs to be done.

To try and convince your client, take a look at the Apple [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/tab-bars/): it's better to use [tab bar icons](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/system-icons/#tab-bar-icons) including a `More` button.

Besides, if you must implement the Dynamic Type feature, the [Large Content Viewer](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-19261.html) will be your friend to enlarge your tab bar items.